# Ruby: Matching a delimiter with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to solve this with a regex pattern, and even though my test passes with this solution, I would like split to only have `["1", "2"]` inside the array. Is there a better way of doing this?

**irb testing**:

```
 s = "//;\n1;2" # when given a delimiter of ';'

 s2 = "1,2,3" # should read between commas

 s3 = "//+\n2+2" # should read between delimiter of '+'

 s.split(/[,\n]|[^0-9]/)

 => ["", "", "", "", "1", "2"]
```

**Production**:

```
module StringCalculator
  def self.add(input)
    solution = input.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).reduce(0, :+)
    input.end_with?("\n") ? nil : solution
  end
end
```

**Test**:

```
context 'when given a newline delimiter' do                                                                                                                          
  it 'should read between numbers' do                                                                                                                              
    expect(StringCalculator.add("1\n2,3")).to eq(6)                                                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                                                                               

  it 'should not end in a newline' do                                                                                                                               
    expect(StringCalculator.add("1,\n")).to be_nil                                                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                                                                              
end 

context 'when given different delimiter' do                                                                                                                         
  it 'should support that delimiter' do                                                                                                                           
    expect(StringCalculator.add("//;\n1;2")).to eq(3)                                                                                                             
  end                                                                                                                                                          
end
```

Comment: when you will be changing your post, write a word **EDIT**, and put the new contents. Don't remove first post. If you remove people will think I am *STUPID*, hope you understand.

Comment: Got it, I've given a little more insight of the problem. @ArupRakshit

Comment: expected output for `"1,2,3"` ?

Comment: Once I have the delimiter, I chain it like this. ```solution = input.split(/[,\n]/).map(&:to_i).reduce(0, :+)```

Comment: I think my previous solution will work still,

Comment: Just revert it to the old post, and ask a new question with your new thought.

Comment: It works, but not with ```'1,2,3'``` or even `'1'`.

Comment: `s.scan(/\d+/) # => ["1", "2", "3"]`

Comment: Please read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: I've read this post years ago @theTinMan What are you suggesting?

Comment: I'm suggesting that trying to use a pattern to split the string results in too complex a solution. `scan`, using `\d+` is the better way to go, then determine what your operator is. That article is about using as simple a pattern as possible; Too many times people try to do too much with them, and paint themselves into a corner with a pattern they can't maintain or that has holes in it that causes it to return bad values. You're trying to split using a complex pattern. Instead, `scan` with a simple one.

Comment: I see what you're saying. The only difficult thing to handle now is when the delimiter is a numerical value such as ```//1\n212```. This would be considered incorrect. How would you go about resolving this? If you can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it a lot. @theTinMan

Comment: Where are you getting such data? That's a terrible format.

Comment: See my answer. You need to supply a list of possible inputs in your question, instead of incrementally changing the scope. And, for each input, you need to show the acceptable output. Failing to do that leads to questions that creep along, like this one, and have no easily discernible answer, which does no good to you or to those who might want an answer to a similar question.

Comment: Hey dude I voted not to close this question but you need to immediately say what 'this' is in your opening section more clearly. It kind of pissed me off that you used "this" like in JavaScript but IRL where "this" is whatever YOU are thinking before you post. You have to tell US what that is first. It helps to tell a bit of story

Comment: You're right, edited again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple using [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan) :

```
s = "//;\n1;2"
s.scan(/\d/) # => ["1", "2"]
```

`/\d/` - **A digit character (`[0-9]`)**

**Note :**

If you have a string like below then, you should use `/\d+/`.

```
s = "//;\n11;2"
s.scan(/\d+/) # => ["11", "2"]
```

Comment: I had done that the first go round, but the problem wants me to actually read numbers between those characters. I feel like I'm cheating with scan haha. http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/

Comment: To be honest, splitting at `^0-9` is pretty much the same as scanning for `0-9` ;-)

Comment: @p11y No.. see this `s = "//;\n11;2"
s.split(/[^0-9]/) # => ["", "", "", "", "11", "2"]`, then you need too do extra work, by clearing `""`.

Comment: I just feel that I'm getting away from reading a delimiter. The problem wants me to be able to read numbers between any given delimiter. In this case, it's a ```;```. How can I get rid of those empty strings?

Comment: I understand what the difference of the output is, my comment was directed at the OP, because he said it was "cheating" to scan for decimals. I was trying to say that he was already "cheating" by his definition in his original solution.

Comment: Does the string always start with `//;\n` ? What's the meaning of this?

Comment: @p11y Ok... feeling sleepy... so couldn't understand you.. Here 4-10 AM :-)

Comment: No, the string only starts with ```//``` when a delimiter is given. Otherwise it's a comma. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @TheGrayFox do `s = "//;\n11;2"
s.match(/(\d+);(\d+)/).captures # => ["11", "2"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting data that looks like this string: `//1\n212`

If you're getting the data as a file, then treat it as two separate lines. If it's a string, then, again, treat it as two separate lines. In either case it'd look like

```
//1
212
```

when output.

If it's a string:

```
input = "//1\n212".split("\n")
delimiter = input.first[2] # => "1"
values = input.last.split(delimiter) # => ["2", "2"]
```

If it's a file:

```
line = File.foreach('foo.txt')
delimiter = line.next[2] # => "1"
values = line.next.chomp.split(delimiter) # => ["2", "2"]
```

Comment: The module I've written with the class method ```add()``` is just passed a string. Even though this isn't covered in the spec, I want all ends to be covered. I didn't write a test for this problem, but I think I could raise an error when a situation like this is met. Thanks for the insight.